# Can't use own property in JavaScript Object's function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the following code:

```
var x = {
    editBox:  _editBox,
    comboBox: _comboBox,
    getExchangeRate: function() {
        var r = parseFloat(_editBox.val());
        return isNaN(r) ? null : r;
    }
}
```

My question is about the use of `_editBox` in `getExchangeRate()`.

I'm creating a JavaScript object, which has two value properties and a function property. But why can't the function use `editBox`? It's undefined if I try.

And how can it use `_editBox`? It could be much later when the function gets called. I understand there is some work being done under the hood to make it available, but how do I know it will still be valid? Wouldn't it make more sense if I could use `editBox` instead?

Having come from other languages, that's certainly what seems more logical.

Comment: Where are you setting `_editBox` in the first place?

Comment: `editBox` isn't defined. You'd want to use `x.editBox` (or `this.editBox` but I don't like that)

Comment: @Adam I don't think so... http://jsfiddle.net/yBLsK/

Comment: @Adam [No, it's not](http://jsfiddle.net/aC8v7/1/): see the log!

Comment: Who the heck is downvoting the question and voting to close it? What's the problem? The question even got an upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why can't the function use editBox? It's undefined if I try.

It is a property of the object, not an in-scope variable.

`this.editBox` will probably work (assuming are you calling `getExchangeRate` in the right context (i.e. `x.getExchangeRate()`).

> And how can it use _editBox?

Because the variable is in scope.

> It could be much later when the function gets called.

That doesn't really matter

> how do I know it will still be valid?

You control when and if it gets overwritten.

Comment: Thanks, looks like `this.editBox` is what I need. But with regards to the last question, the variable `_editBox` will be *long* gone when `getExchangeRate()` is called. So I was just wondering how I know it will still make sense when it is used here.

Comment: @JonathanWood: The function you define is a closure that is able to access `_editBox`, even if the function is called in a totally different scope. That's how closures work :)

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no variable such as `editBox`, but there is `_editBox`. I think you are looking for

```
this.editBox.val()
```

If you call the function as `x.getExchangeRate()`, then `this` inside the function will refer to `x` and you can access its property `editBox`. [See the MDN documentation for more information about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

---

> Having come from other languages, that's certainly what seems more logical.

JavaScript is not like Java where instance members are automatically in scope of the methods. There is no implicit connection between a function and the object it is a property value of. That's because functions are first-class objects, they don't "belong" to anyone. And JS has lexical scope.

Consider this example:

```
var name = 'bar';

function foo() {
   console.log(name);
}

var obj = {
   name: 'baz',
   prop: foo
};
```

As you can see, we defined `foo` "independently" from `obj`. `obj.name` doesn't magically become `name` inside the function if it is called as `obj.prop()`.

Comment: Just had to shut down my dev system to leave. But, yes, if `this.editBox` is available, that would make sense. Will test when I return.